# Multiple Modals on One Page in a For Loop using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, modal-dialog

I am trying to allow multiple modals in a single page. The html set-up is:

```
      <div class="grid-item">
        <img id="Img1" src="https://something"/>
      </div>

      <div id="myModal1" class="modal">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
          <div id="caption">Final Product: Folding Paduak Timepiece</div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item">
        <img id="Img2" src="https://somethingelse"/>
      </div>

      <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <img class="modal-content" id="img02">
          <div id="caption">Angled shot of unhinged product</div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item">
        <img id="Img3" src="https://somethingagain"/>
      </div>

      <div id="myModal3" class="modal">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <img class="modal-content" id="img03">
          <div id="caption">Downwards view of unhinged product</div>
      </div>
```

I managed to do this by repeating more code than I should. This is demonstrated below; this worked:

```
var modal1 = document.getElementById('myModal1');
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');
var modal3 = document.getElementById('myModal3');

var img1 = document.getElementById('Img1');
var img2 = document.getElementById('Img2');
var img3 = document.getElementById('Img3');

var modalImg1 = document.getElementById("img01");
var modalImg2 = document.getElementById("img02");
var modalImg3 = document.getElementById("img03");

var captionText1 = document.getElementById("caption1");
var captionText2 = document.getElementById("caption2");
var captionText3 = document.getElementById("caption3");

img1.onclick = function(){
    modal[i].style.display = "block";
    modalImg1.src = this.src;
    captionText1.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
img2.onclick = function(){
    modal2.style.display = "block";
    modalImg2.src = this.src;
    captionText2.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
img3.onclick = function(){
    modal3.style.display = "block";
    modalImg3.src = this.src;
    captionText3.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];
var span3 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[2];

span1.onclick = function() { 
    modal1.style.display = "none";
}
span2.onclick = function() { 
    modal2.style.display = "none";
}
span3.onclick = function() { 
    modal3.style.display = "none";
}
```

In order to streamline this, I created a for-loop. This is demonstrated below; this did not work:

```
var = modal[];
var = img[];
var = modalImg[];
var = captionText[];
var = span[];

for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    var modal[i] = document.getElementById("myModal"+ i.toString());
    document.write(modal[i]);
    var img[i] = document.getElementById("Img" + i.toString());
    var modalImg[i] = document.getElementById("img0" + i.toString());
    var captionText[i] = document.getElementById("caption");
    img[i].onclick = function(){
        modal[i].style.display = "block";
        modalImg[i].src = this.src;
        captionText[i].innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
    var span[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[(i-1)];
    span[i].onclick = function() { 
    modal[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I am fairly new to JavaScript, and am not quite sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the full [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a88xomky/19/) you provided, I can see that you are already using jquery for your grid-layout. Using jquery, I can give a simpler solution - here is the [modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a88xomky/22/).

Basically you can add a `data-index` property to the relevant images and modals, then use a single event listener to manage modal opens. The relevant javascript is:

```
/* jquery and data-property method */
$(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.modal-img', function(event) {
    var $img = $(event.target);
    var index = $img.data('index');
    var $modal = $("#myModal" + index);
    $modal.find('img').attr('src', $img.attr('src'));
    $modal.find('#caption').text($img.attr('alt'));
    $modal.css('display', 'block');
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.modal .close', function(event) {
    var $modal = $(event.target).closest('.modal');
    $modal.css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

That, along with adding the `data-index` to your html as in the fiddle, will work.

If you want to go even further, a couple of pointers. Jquery can be used to fairly easily do things like "find the `.modal` element that follows the current `img` element", etc, eliminating the need for indexing all together. Also, your code would still work if you just referenced a single modal instead of one per image... you are dynamically updating the image source and caption each time the modal is shown, so a single modal would work. To make that happen, just delete all but one modal from the html, and make sure it is referenced by `$modal` in the code provided.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript functions take their context with them, even when they are executed later on. Within your `for` loop you define two functions (one to open the modal and one to close). Each of those functions is accessing the loop variable `i` as it is defined outside the function. If `i` is modified (as it is during the loop), the function accesses the new, modified value when it executes.

(this is both a big difficulty and a big opportunity in javascript!)

You can achieve what you want in this case simply by defining a new variable with in your for loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++){
  var modal[i] = document.getElementById("myModal"+ i.toString());
  document.write(modal[i]);
  var img[i] = document.getElementById("Img" + i.toString());
  var modalImg[i] = document.getElementById("img0" + i.toString());
  var captionText[i] = document.getElementById("caption");
  // before we define any functions, give the current index a new variable
  var currentIndex = i;
  // use the new variable in the functions to be executed later
  img[i].onclick = function(){
    modal[currentIndex].style.display = "block";
    modalImg[currentIndex].src = this.src;
    captionText[currentIndex].innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
  var span[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[(i-1)];
  span[i].onclick = function() { 
    modal[currentIndex].style.display = "none";
  }
```

}

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your response! While that makes sense, unfortunately, it has not fixed the problem. For clarity's sake, I have placed the problem I am having in a jsfiddle, which may be accessed at: https://jsfiddle.net/a88xomky/19/. There I have posted both the noniterative working solution and the iterative nonworking solution.

Comment: ok, looking at your fiddle, I came up with a better answer. It's different, so I'll post it as a new answer...